# What time can I expect previous days data when using BigQuery linking with Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I set up BigQuery linking with Google Analytics 4 two days ago on the 26th (daily export) and as of this morning have data in for the 26th. It is currently 8:30AM UTC on the 28th, should I have data for the 27th already? My tables themselves are located in the US and I am located in a UTC timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238#step3&zippy=%2Cin-this-article) once you've linked Google Analytics to Bigquery data should start flowing into your Bigquery project within 24 hrours.

If you enable daily export, then 1 file will be exported each day that contains the previous day’s data (generally, during early afternoon in the [time zone you set for reporting](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9304153#:%7E:text=select%20the%20reporting%20time%20zone%C2%A0and%C2%A0currency.)).
However, if you want to recieve the data in Bigquery within few minutes, you can enable Streaming export.

Comment: Thank you, it came in late afternoon UTC in the end - I think it was later than usual since it was newly linked.